# Inserting Data to a Table Retrieved from Two Merged Tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I have two courses. In each course there are several assignments. A student can follow both courses.
I have the following  tables:`courses,student_courses,course1`
My *courses* table has st_index,assignmnet_no,marks,course_no as the fields
 and *student_courses* table  has st_index,course1,course2 where 1is inserted if the student follows course1 or course2 .
Table *course1* has Student_Index, Assignment1, Assignment2,Assignment3 as fields.

I have inserted my data into tables `courses,student_courses`. By retrieving data from these I want to come up with `course1` table.`course1`
should look as follows:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['course']=="Course1"){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT student_index FROM student_courses WHERE course1=1");
    while($index=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $index[0];
        echo"<br>";
        $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_no='Course1' AND st_index='$index[0]'");
        while($i2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            $ass_no=$i2['assignment_no'];
            if($ass_no=='1'){
                echo $index[0];
                $result3=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course1(Student_Index,Assignment1) VALUES('$index[0]','$i2[marks]')"); 
                }
            if($ass_no=='2'){
                echo $index[0];
                $result4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course1(Assignment2) VALUES('$i2[marks]')"); 
                }
            if($ass_no=='3'){

                $result5=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course1(Assignment3) VALUES('$i2[marks]')"); 
                }

            } 


        } 

    }

?>
```

The problem is for course1 only the first student_index assignment values gets inserted. In there also for the same student_index the values gets inserted into two separate rows. What I am trying to do is when we consider a row in course1, which is identified by student_index that row should have all the assignment marks of that student.  How can I achieve this?

That is say I have two records that match the conditions for the table `course1` as 945,568.
In the `course1` it only gets inserted records for 965 and it also looks like below. [image]. The two rows should be one, under same index_no

In order to check what is going wrong inside first while loop I used `echo $index[0]` . It prints 945,568 both.  But in the if statements inside the other while loop only 945 gets printed. That is when the loop is run for the second time I think the line `$result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_no='Course1' AND st_index='$index[0]'");` doesn't get executed.

Comment: Can you provide the table structure in table form? How it looks at the moment and how it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in SQL, **INSERT** always adds a new row.  You've inserted a row for each mark, but only provided a Student_Index for one of them (thus the empty indexes on subsequent rows).  What you *want* is the **UPDATE** command.

So let's just use INSERT once to create a row for each student, just before the inner WHILE:

```
INSERT INTO course1(Student_Index) VALUES('$index[0]')
```

and then fill the fields by replacing your INSERT statements with (e.g. for assignment 1):

```
UPDATE course1 SET assignment1 = '$i2[marks]' WHERE Student_Index = '$index[0]'
```

*Alternatively*, you can accomplish this in SQL alone with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE course1
SELECT s1.st_index,
       a1.marks AS Assignment1,
       a2.marks AS Assignment2,
       a3.marks AS Assignment3
  FROM courses a1, courses a2, course a3
 WHERE a1.course_no = 1
   AND a2.course_no = 1
   AND a3.course_no = 1
   AND a1.assignment_no = 1
   AND a2.assignment_no = 2
   AND a3.assignment_no = 3
   AND a1.st_index = a2.st_index
   AND a1.st_index = a3.st_index;
```

We've joined the course table three times to select out the three rows where the three marks reside for with course_no=1 and constrained them to be the same student in all three rows.  This will return one row for each student.  Also, With this solution there is no need for a reference to the student_courses table at all since you can infer the enrollment of a student in a course by the presence of marks in the course table.